# What is the result for EM algorithm in smoothed LDA model?

Tags: expectation-maximization, variational-bayes, latent-dirichlet-alloc

In the original LDA paper ([Blei2003](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/blei03a/blei03a.pdf)), EM algorithm estimates $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in Fig.5. So, what is the result for Fig.7? Will it give estimation of $\alpha, \beta$ or $\alpha, \eta$?

And, if I get $\alpha, \eta$ in Fig.7, how do I get $\theta, z, \beta$, which is what I am actually interested in?